# Matching two files and print all columns

Tags: linux, join, awk

I have two files I want to match according to column 1 in file 1 and column 2 in file 2.

File 1:

```
1000019 -0.013936       0.0069218       -0.0048443      -0.0053688
1000054 0.013993        0.0044969       -0.0050022      -0.0043233
```

File 2:

```
5131885 1000019
1281471 1000054
```

I would like to print all columns after matching.
Expected output (file 3):

```
5131885 1000019 -0.013936       0.0069218       -0.0048443      -0.0053688
1281471 1000054 0.013993        0.0044969       -0.0050022      -0.0043233
```

I tried the following:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$2;next} ($2 in arr){print $0,arr[$2]}' file1 file2 > file3
join file1 file2 > file3 #after sorting
```

Comment: Try join -1 1 -2 2 file1 file2 or something like that.  https://linux.die.net/man/1/join

Comment: I edited the post with the expected output.

Comment: join -1 1 -2 2 file1  file2 -o 2.2,2.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should work

```
awk 'NR==FNR {r[$2]=$1; next}{print r[$1], $0}' $file2 $file1
```

**Output**

```
5131885 1000019 -0.013936       0.0069218       -0.0048443      -0.0053688
1281471 1000054 0.013993        0.0044969       -0.0050022      -0.0043233
```